# vuforia unity reticle as a pointer

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

In my vuforia unity project I have copied reticle from AR-VR sample and attached with AR camera as in my project. it works perfectly and serve as a reticle. I wanted to write pointer enter event when the reticle crosses 3d object which is produced upon image detection. I have attached physics ray cast with camera.
The reticle is not working as a pointer.
is there anything I missed?